# Python problem with def, bug with a var inside the def, variable not working in if statement

Tags: python, function

I made a `def roomidea(test)` with the inputs inside it, I believe I did the `return` right. Now under the first `if` statement I have `sBedsize, sRoomview, sVehicle, iRoomnum, iNights = roomidea(test)` so it reads the function. The problem is when I run the code it displays

> `sBedsize` is not defined

even though I have all of that under the `if` statement. Why doesn't this work?

I've been working on this project for awhile, now I think my second `def price(test2)` works but I'm not sure yet as the first `def` is the main problem so far, I would appreciate any tips or help or anything that may help me solve or learn how to solve this issue.

Now a big concern I'm also having is that I use many variables in the second `def`, meaning I use variables to solve other variables like `dTotalqav` and having `dPrice1`, `dPrice5`, `dResortfee1`, and `dResortfee2` all inside the same `def`. Because of this would this calculate right or just produce another bug?

I'm running this in PyCharm, in case that's relevant.

```
import time
def roomidea(test):
    sBedsize = input("For your room do you want a queen-size bed or a king-size bed? Type Queen for queen-size or King for king-size:\t")
    sRoomview = input("For your room do you want the standard view or the atrium view? Type Standard for standard-view or Atrium for atrium-view:\t")
    sVehicle = input("Will you be parking at our hotel? Type Yes if you are, or No if you are not:\t")
    iRoomnum = int(input("Please enter the amount of rooms you wish to check out:\t"))
    iNights = int(input("Please enter the amount of nights you wish to stay:\t"))
    return sBedsize, sRoomview, sVehicle, iRoomnum, iNights

def price(test2):
    dPrice1 = iNights * 280
    dPrice2 = iNights * 320
    dPrice3 = iNights * 295.50
    dPrice4 = iNights * 335.50
    dPrice5 = iNights * 15.75
    dResortfee1 = iNights * 20
    dResortfee2 = iRoomnum * 20
    dTotalqs = dPrice1 + dPrice5 + dResortfee1 + dResortfee2
    dTotalqa = dPrice2 + dPrice5 + dResortfee1 + dResortfee2
    dTotalqsv = dPrice1 + dResortfee1 + dResortfee2
    dTotalqav = dPrice2 + dResortfee1 + dResortfee2
    dTotalks = dPrice3 + dPrice5 + dResortfee1 + dResortfee2
    dTotalka = dPrice4 + dPrice5 + dResortfee1 + dResortfee2
    dTotalksv = dPrice3 + dResortfee1 + dResortfee2
    dTotalkav = dPrice4 + dResortfee1 + dResortfee2
    dTaxqs = dTotalqs * 0.15
    dTaxqa = dTotalqa * 0.15
    dTaxqsv = dTotalqsv * 0.15
    dTaxqav = dTotalqav * 0.15
    dTaxks = dTotalks * 0.15
    dTaxka = dTotalka * 0.15
    dTaxksv = dTotalksv * 0.15
    dTaxkav = dTotalkav * 0.15
    dOverallqs = dTotalqs + dTaxqs
    dOverallqa = dTotalqa + dTaxqs
    dOverallqsv = dTotalqsv + dTaxqs
    dOverallqav = dTotalqav + dTaxqs
    dOverallks = dTotalks + dTaxqs
    dOverallka = dTotalka + dTaxqs
    dOverallksv = dTotalksv + dTaxqs
    dOverallkav = dTotalkav + dTaxqs
    return dPrice1, dPrice2, dPrice3, dPrice4, dPrice5, dResortfee1, dResortfee2, dTotalqs, dTotalqa, dTotalqsv, dTotalqav, dTotalks, dTotalka, dTotalksv, dTotalkav, dTaxqs, dTaxqa, dTaxqsv, dTaxqav, dTaxks, dTaxka, dTaxksv, dTaxkav, dOverallqs, dOverallqa, dOverallqsv, dOverallqav, dOverallks, dOverallka, dOverallksv, dOverallkav



if  sBedsize == "Queen" and sRoomview == "Standard" and sVehicle == "Yes":
    sBedsize, sRoomview, sVehicle, iRoomnum, iNights = roomidea(test)
    print("The price for a Queen-Size bed with the Standard view and you are parking a vehicle, this comes to the total of $%.2f" % dTotalqs + " If this is how you want your room, type Yes, if you want to pick another option, type No.")
elif sBedsize == "Queen" and sRoomview == "Atrium" and sVehicle == "Yes":
    sBedsize, sRoomview, sVehicle, iRoomnum, iNights = roomidea()
    print("The price of Queen-Size bed with the Atrium view and you are parking a vehicle, this comes to the total of $%.2f" % dTotalqa + " If this is how you want your room, type Yes, if you want to pick another option, type No.")
elif sBedsize == "Queen" and sRoomview == "Standard" and sVehicle == "No":
    sBedsize, sRoomview, sVehicle, iRoomnum, iNights = roomidea()
    print("The price for a Queen-Size bed with the Standard view and you are not parking a vehicle, this comes to the total of $%.2f" % dTotalqsv + " If this is how you want your room, type Yes, if you want to pick another option, type No.")
elif sBedsize == "Queen" and sRoomview == "Atrium" and sVehicle == "No":
    sBedsize, sRoomview, sVehicle, iRoomnum, iNights = roomidea()
    print("The price for a Queen-Size bed with the Atrium view and you are not parking a vehicle, this comes to the total of $%.2f" % dTotalqav + " If this is how you want your room, type Yes, if you want to pick another option, type No.")
elif sBedsize == "King" and sRoomview == "Standard" and sVehicle == "Yes":
    sBedsize, sRoomview, sVehicle, iRoomnum, iNights = roomidea()
    print("The price for a King-Size bed with the Standard view and you are parking a vehicle, this comes to the total of $%.2f" % dTotalks + " If this is how you want your room, type Yes, if you want to pick another option, type No.")
elif sBedsize == "King" and sRoomview == "Atrium" and sVehicle == "Yes":
    sBedsize, sRoomview, sVehicle, iRoomnum, iNights = roomidea()
    print("The price for a King-Size bed with the Atrium view and you are parking a vehicle, this comes to the total of $%.2f" % dTotalka + " If this is how you want your room, type Yes, if you want to pick another option, type No.")
elif sBedsize == "King" and sRoomview == "Standard" and sVehicle == "No":
    sBedsize, sRoomview, sVehicle, iRoomnum, iNights = roomidea()
    print("The price for a King-Size bed with the Standard view and you are not parking a vehicle, this comes to the total of $%.2f" % dTotalksv + " If this is how you want your room, type Yes, if you want to pick another option, type No.")
elif sBedsize == "King" and sRoomview == "Atrium" and sVehicle == "No":
    sBedsize, sRoomview, sVehicle, iRoomnum, iNights = roomidea()
    print("The price for a King-Size bed with the Standard view and you are not parking a vehicle, this comes to the total of $%.2f" % dTotalkav + " If this is how you want your room, type Yes, if you want to pick another option, type No.")
else:
    print("You did not enter the information correctly")
time.sleep(5)
feedback = input("Would you like to change your room choices? Type Yes or No for the options").upper()
if feedback == "YES":
    print("Thank you for picking a room with us, I hope you enjoy your room and we are hoping to see you back again!")
elif feedback == "NO":
    print("We are sorry that the room you picked isn't how you wanted it, please retype how you want your room, if you want to leave just type quit")
    time.sleep(5)
    print(test)
```

Also lastly for the import time and later the time.sleep(5) then the print(test) afterwards, I'm using that so it reprints the original input so they can change up their inputs and maybe if they picked "Queen Standard Yes 1 1" but they made a mistake they can type no and change their inputs to something like "King Standard Yes 1 1" Anyways sorry for this quick question but these are the basic problems I'm running into.

Comment: Aside: _please_ don't use Hungarian notation, especially with Python (a strongly but dynamically typed language where variables don't have a declared type). There's an official [style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Read it. Learn it. Use it. Love it. Even with statically-typed languages I'm not aware of a single modern style guide for any language that endorses Hungarian Notation. IMO it's just a bad idea.

Comment: My Professor requires us to use s/i/d before each var name with the letter after the s/i/d to be capitalized. If that is what you are talking about when you say Hungarian Notation, but it's a requirement so I can't get rid of it. Also I will reduce the code a bit as I understand what you are talking about. I'll do that right now and if it is reduced to much I would appreciate if somebody would let me know.

Comment: It's very difficult to read, but if your professor requires it I guess we'll have to live with it. (Though that's enough for me to doubt whether this is a professor you should be learning Python from.)

Comment: We started using visual logic where he required us to use it for visual logic, once he started us with python he told us to keep using the same thing when naming variables, I'm sorry its hard to read

Comment: As I usually respond to problems like this, you probably have some minor problem in you logic that can be found by developing better debugging skills. Invest an hour or so in familiarizing yourself with [pdb](https://medium.com/instamojo-matters/become-a-pdb-power-user-e3fc4e2774b2) (link chosen semi arbitrarily; there are many resources for learning Python debugging skills). Use this to step through you code line by line and reason carefully about which parts aren't working as you expect them to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the function and assign those variables *before* you can query them in your `if` statement.

Here is a simplified example:

```
def foo():
    # These variables only exist inside the function
    one = 1
    two = 2
    three = 3

    # This doesn't cause them to exist outside of the function; it "gives them"
    # as a result of calling the function later
    return one, two, three

# a, b, and c don't exist yet so I can't use them in an if statement here

# This is where we run the code contained in the function foo and bind the
# returned values to variables (they can be named differently, here we use a,
# b, and c)
a, b, c = foo()

# a, b, and c now exist as variables in the main program and they hold the values
# that were returned from the function. Now we can use them in an `if` statement, e.g.
if a or b or c:
    print('Success')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time of reading my problem and trying to solve it, under the first if statement it says:

sBedsize, sRoomview, sVehicle, iRoomnum, iNights = roomidea(test)

I thought this is how I would call it? did i do it wrong? Thank you for your time!

Comment: @JoeCline, I've updated my answer to try to more clearly show how this works. The function still needs to be called—that's when the code in the function runs. And if you want to capture the return values from the function they must be used in the main program. Here we assign them to variables `a`, `b`, and `c`.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know if this works yet but I think I understand what you are saying and I'm going to apply it to my code. But again I appreciate your answer and the time you took.

Comment: @JoeCline, I'm just now seeing that you _do_ call the function, but you do it inside the `if` statement. That's when the variables `sBedsize` get created, so the containing `if` can't reference them. Call the function and assign the variables _before_ your `if` statement.